# Celery and Redis error when running celery

Tags: django, redis, celery

I'm making a django app with celery and redis that udpates stock prices asynchronously. I'm working on the background tasks right now and celery won't run properly. I turn on the Redis server then django server and when I turn on the celery one with celery -A celery worker -l info I get this error...

```
[2023-07-24 20:25:37,798: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 61] Connection refused.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
```

There's also this above it and I want to point out that it's not connecting to my broker url I provided it..

```
[2023-07-24 20:25:37,688: WARNING/MainProcess] No hostname was supplied. Reverting to default 'localhost'

celery@Gabes-MBP.hsd1.ca.comcast.net v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)

macOS-13.2.1-arm64-arm-64bit 2023-07-24 20:25:37

[config]
.> app:         default:0x101ecc220 (.default.Loader)
.> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
.> results:     disabled://
.> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
.> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)

[queues]
.> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
```

This is my settings.py,

```
#celery settings
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = 'application.json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULER = 'django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler'
```

This is my celery.py,

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os

from celery import Celery

# from django.conf import settings

# from celery.schedules import crontab

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings.\_base')

app = Celery('myproject')
app.conf.enable_utc = False
app.conf.update(timezone = 'America/New_York')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.conf.beat_scheduler = {
'every-15-seconds': {
'task': 'apps.portfolio.tasks.update_ticker',
'schedule': 15,
'args': (\['IEMG', 'AAPL', 'SYF', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'GOOG', 'V', 'F'\])
},
}

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

I've tried running celery with alternative commands, but that doesn't een start the celery server. I don't know what else to try, help

Comment: excuse the random backslashes (\) stack overflow was screwing with me

Comment: Why did you add extra `_base` in the following line `'myproject.settings.\_base'`. That could be causing an issue. Also you can print the app.conf and check for broker_url before actually starting. This is helpful in debugging. You can also look at other django settings in the file

Comment: @LemonReddy thanks for responding! settings is a directory with settings for each environment (_base.py, dev.py, production.py, etc). _base.py being your standard settings.py (where the celery settings are located). I'll look into your debugging recommendations, thanks again!